# Can I sum up multiple, alternating series capacitors and resistors like this?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, series

[image]

When the components are between each other, can I sum up multiple, alternating series capacitors and resistors like this? Thanks.

Comment: yes  why did you doubt it/

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist because the components are between each other.

Comment: Since they share the same current, the end-points cannot tell the difference in an equivalent circuit. Only a real voltage drop on each and power dissipation may be different for power heat rise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they share the same current, the end-points cannot tell the difference in an equivalent circuit.

Only a real voltage drop on each and power dissipation may be different for power heat rise.